# AngularFire - ReferenceError: Firebase not defined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have included the Firebase and AngularFire js files via CDN. I have injected the AngularFire into my app and thereafter injected the $firebaseArray into my controller. Yet for some reason I am still getting the 'Firebase not defined error' in my dev console.

I have looked at the following links:

[AngularFire - Firebase not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887033/angularfire-firebase-not-defined)

[Firebase Error - "FireBase is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405435/firebase-error-firebase-is-not-defined)

[Angularfire 'Firebase' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021640/angularfire-firebase-is-not-defined)

[Angularfire Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642878/angularfire-uncaught-referenceerror-firebase-is-not-defined)

and none of them addresses my situation. Am I missing something? I am including my code below:

```
//App
angular.module("TestApp", ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'firebase']);

//Controller
angular.module('TestApp')
.controller('DetailsController',['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$http', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $http) {

    console.log($firebaseArray); // <- verified here that the injection works
    var rootRef = new Firebase("https://<my-ref-url>.firebaseio.com");

    //load data from firebase db
    $scope.loadCommunity = function(){

        $scope.hasCommunity = true;
        $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(rootRef);

    };

}]);
```

and the following is the code I included in the index.html file:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "MY API KEY HERE",
    authDomain: "<my-ref-url>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "<my-ref-url>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularFire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get the `rootRef` using `new Firebase("https://<my-ref-url>.firebaseio.com");` and thats from the legacy 2.x firebase sdk.

This is one of the changes of firebase 3.x. You have to do this in a slightly different way.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

You can do some tests using this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/8/)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. I was following the David Yeast tutorial video on the Google Developers channel on Youtube. I didn't realize that it  was outdated. 
Cheers!

Comment: How to resole this prolem when use ES6. `import 'firebase'` does not work.